# PostgreSQL pg_hba.conf Issue

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

In pg_hba.conf, I have

```
host    all             all             127.0.0.1/32            md5
host    all             all             samenet            md5
```

I also added

```
host    all             all             samehost            md5
```

on both.

I am using pgAdminIII, trying create a "New Server Registration". When I connect to (localhost), it works fine. But when I change the host to the actual workstation name it says:

```
FATAL: no pg_hba.conf entry for host "fe80::c81c:9e9c:6570:d0bf%20", user "postgres", database "postgres", SSL off
```

Additional Information

- Operating system: Windows 7 Ultimate 32 bit
- PostgreSQL Server 9.0.2

Any help on this would be highly appreciated.

Comment: That's because when you attempt to connect, you're connecting to the IPv6 address, not the IPv4 address and your IPv6 address doesn't exist in your pg_hba.conf. Add your IPv6 address to your pg_hba.conf and reload PostgreSQL.

Comment: try to add you IP on the pg_hba.conf, something like "host all all fe80::c81c:9e9c:6570:d0bf/128 md5"

Comment: According to the manual, "samenet" matches to any address in any subnet that the server is directly connected to, and "samehost" matches to any of the server's own IP addresses, I have tried both with no luck.

Comment: Try adjusting `listen_adresses` property in postgresql.conf (http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.0/static/runtime-config-connection.html#GUC-LISTEN-ADDRESSES). Probably default value is just localhost.

Comment: The default setting was "listen_addresses = '*'". I did not have to change that. :)

Comment: If I add the IPv6 address to pg_hba.conf, it works, "samehost" and "samenet" mean nothing.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is the issue of PostgreSQL installations on Windows computers having IPv6 enabled.  Temporary workaround would be passing paramter "-h 127.0.01" as described in this article.

http://postgresql.1045698.n5.nabble.com/FATAL-no-pg-hba-conf-entry-for-host-1-td1873063.html

Comment: Or -h <your actual host IPv4> if you are running this on a remote machine. If you use the machine name, it will resolve to v6, and not work.

Answer (score 5):

This has been answered by other user here, but I want to show the answer here to make more clear for others:

In pg_hba.conf, add your ipv6 address like this:

```
host      all        all       fe80::c81c:9e9c:6570:d0bf/128       md5
```

fe80::c81c:9e9c:6570:d0bf is your ipv6 address.

Answer (score 3):

Note that the interface enumeration code that `samehost` and `samenet` rely on is very platform-dependent.  (There are currently 5 separate implementations for different platforms.)  So what works for one setup might not work somewhere else.

That said, the analogous setup works for me on Linux, that is, I can connect to the database server on the local host using

```
psql -d postgres -h 'fe80::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx%eth0'
```

after setting `listening_addresses` and `samenet` appropriately.

So it's conceivable that the interface enumeration code in Windows somehow fails to include the link-local addresses.

If you have isolated this problem enough, I would send a bug report to PostgreSQL to analyze the issue further.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and solved it by turning off ipv6 support on both machines.  Not sure if this is an option for you.

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
host      all        all       ::1/128       md5
```

for the localhost.

Answer (score 0):

Turn off IPV6 on adapters that you can.
After that, do

```
netsh interface teredo set state disabled
```

This will disable virtual network interfaces that you can't see from GUI.